# Change MYSQL date format

Tags: mysql, date, format

I have a table in MYSQL of which 3 columns have dates and they are formatted in the not desired way.

Currently I have: **mm/dd/yyyy** and I want to change those dates into **dd/mm/yyyy**.

Table name is Vehicles and the columns names are:

```
CRTD
INSR
SERD
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current datatype for your column is not `date` right? you need to convert it to date first using `STR_TO_DATE()` and convert back to string

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(colName, '%c/%d/%Y'), '%d/%c/%Y')
FROM table1
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ee75/2)

Comment: Do I run that as an SQL Query? and it would select ALL dates?

Comment: @jQuerybeast yes, I'll add a demo on the answer. Please wait :)

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to exclude first 5 rows? Cause Ive changed them already. And I should add that the Column's type is VARCHAR

Comment: @jQuerybeast what do you mean exclude 5 rows? see the fiddle above. uhmm followup question, why are you storing that as `VARCHAR`? best way to store that as `DATE`

Comment: Changing it to date then. Its the first time im ever experiencing with MYSQL databases and its all a test case.

Comment: much better if you do that :)

Comment: Error: #1054 - Unknown column 'colName' in 'field list'

Comment: replace `colName` to the original name of your column in your table. `colName` there is just an example.

Comment: Omg, it has changed every single date to 0000-00-00

Comment: Please dont tell me this has no undo

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18142/discussion-between-john-woo-and-jquerybeast)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select date_format(curdate(), '%d/%m/%Y');
```

In you case you have to use this query.If all three columns are of datetime type

```
select date_format(CRTD, '%d/%m/%Y'),
       date_format(INSR, '%d/%m/%Y'),
       date_format(SERD, '%d/%m/%Y')
From yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `date_format()` function to format your dates any way you want.

If you want to change the format for *every* date on *any* database you work with, you should change the value of the `date_format` system variable.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Vehicles SET yourdatecolumn=DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(yourdatecolumn, '%c-%d-%Y'), '%d-%c-%Y')